# how can Send parameters to a local file in a WebView in android?

Tags: android, html, webview, parameters

working on a native Android app. I am able to load a local file index.html into a WebView:
The web url loads fine. Now, I would like to load the web with some parameters, in the same way one types this in the browser:
So I can get those values inside the javascript of the html file. Is there any way to send parameters to a local html file?

```
html:
<input type="hidden" name="deviceid" id="deviceid"/>
```

i pass the device_id on local html file.

Answer (score 1):

You can send them as get parameters while loading your html in WebView itself, and then later catch it in your JavaScript using `window.location.href` property. Something like this:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("/assets/index.html?foo=bar");
```

**edit**

To send the Device-ID, use the below code instead:

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String did =  tm.getDeviceId();
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("/assets/index.html?DeviceID=" + did);
```

Comment: but how is it possible what we have to do for that i also getting same issue? i would like to send device id when i load the url can you give some more code? thank in advance

Comment: @Google See updated answer, I've included the code to fetch DeviceID.

Comment: but where can i put my url which load the main page?

Comment: I just showed you how to send device ID from your Java code to the WebView html. If what you are calling the "Main Page" is a separate html, then I assume you can do so easily by picking the `window.location.href` attribute. Maybe if you can share the whole code, it will help.